# Java: using Filewriter to edit all files of any file name

Tags: java, file, detection

For an assignment, I have to make an encrypter and decrypter. These will take all files in a folder path and encode them. I know how to specify the path of the folder. Problem is, I don't know the file names,so I need to detect all file names in the folder. I am only using text documents for this exercise,so that should make it easier.

As of now, the only classes I am allowed to use are:

FileWriter (Which all constructors require a name. IT WOULD HELP IF THERE WAS A WAY AROUND THIS!!!)
File
PrintWriter
Scanner

I was thinking it'd be something like this:
`new FileWriter( (*)".txt");`

with the * being any file name. But that doesn't work.

Comment: The list() method of java.io.File, will give you all files in a given folder (assuming you create the File object with a folder path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an File object with the path of the directory.

```
File directory = new File("your/path");
```

The File class has a member function called listFiles, which has an overload that accepts a FilenameFilter. FilenameFilter is an interface which has a method accept, by implementing this function you can specify what files you want to include. For example:

```
File[] txtfiles = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
    {
        return filename.endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Now txtfiles will contain all files in the specified directory that contain the suffix .txt. Creating a FileWriter for these files isn't that hard anymore:

```
for(File file : txtfiles)
{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    /*Your other code*/
}
```